# I get Type Error on a retuned matrix tryng to build a string

Tags: python

For the following code tryng to print a grid for a naval battle game i get the error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
   import numpy as np

    def hide():
        ship_pos=[]
        for i in range(0,2):
            ship_pos.append(np.random.randint(0,5))
        return ship_pos
    pass

    def build_grid(shot):
        griglia=[['O','O','O','O','O'],
                 ['O','O','O','O','O'],
                 ['O','O','O','O','O'],
                 ['O','O','O','O','O'],
                 ['O','O','O','O','O']]
        griglia[shot[0]][shot[1]]='X'
        return grid
    pass

    def print_grid(griglia):
        row=" "
        for i in range(0,5):
            for j in range(0,5):
                row+=griglia[i][j]+" " #here
            print("\n")
            row=" "
    pass        
    grid=build_grid([2,3])
    nave=hide()
    print_grid(grid)
```

Comment: function build_grid return undefined variable, change to return griglia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues with your code.

1. In `build_grid()` you return `grid` which does not exist. Changing to `return griglia` is what I think you want.
2. In `print_grid()` you `print("\n")` with just prints a new line. Try printing row - `print(row)`.

With those two changes I get the result below - is that what you desire?:

```
O O O O O 
O O O O O 
O O O X O 
O O O O O 
O O O O O
```